# Twitter API: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, api, twitter

I try to access the Twitter API.
For that I have a function get_API and a yaml file with the Twitter keys.

I can`t solve the following Error:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

YAML-File:

```
credentials=[{"database":{'consumer_API_key':("yH77"), 'consumer_API_secret':("N8s"), 'access_token':("22-kO9"), 'access_token_secret':("yZ7")}}]

 with open("credentials.yaml","w") as f:

    data=yaml.dump(credentials, f)


The get_api:

import yaml

def get_api():
    
    # load yml file to dictionary
    credentials = yaml.safe_load(open('C:/Users/samue/Desktop/BA/PA20-Daten-neu/src/credentials.yaml'))

    consumer_key= credentials["database"]['consumer_API_key']
    consumer_secret= credentials["database"]['consumer_API_secret']
    access_token= credentials["database"]['access_token']
    access_token_secret= credentials["database"]['access_token_secret']
    
    
    # login 
    auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
    
    
    return api
```

Comment: The keys are not the real ones, and shorter, but the same in style.

Comment: Add `credentials = credentials[0]` after loading the credentials.